# bnary tree search time

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

what is the time required to search any random element in a binary tree with n elements?
I have a binary tree (not complete though) with 7 nodes. find the time required to search any random element up to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

First i would say your question is incomplete.secondly if i consider only binary tree then time complexity of finding any random element is O(n) because it is just a simple tree.
it can be compared to simple unsorted array and Binary Search tree whose complexity is O(h) where h is height of BST. 
BT(Binary tree) is equivalent to unsorted array.
BST(Binary search tree ) equivalent to sorted array.